AUC comparison with Delong when i.i.d is broken due to clustered data
I am asked to compare two AUC ROCs and output confidence interval for both.
Delong method allows (and also Fast Delong) to have a stronger test than usual bootstrapping method.
The data I am working with consists of prediction over several screening on patients. So one patient might have different number of screening than another one. This breaks the usual i.i.d assumption.
The seminal paper of Delong method doesn't really discuss the assumption necessary to make it a valid approach in a given case. However it relies on U-statistic.
Here are my three questions:

Is it possible to use Delong on data that has clustered patterns ?
If not are there possibility to adapt Delong ?
If no. Should I rather rely on hierarchical bootstrapping method ?


I found adaptation of Delong method for clustered data:
Nonparametric Analysis of Clustered ROC Curve Data 
